# Basic Auth not working with Angular2

Tags: angular, basic-authentication

I have a post request with Basic authentication.

```js
public login = (resrc: string, item: any): Observable<any> => {
        this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(item['userName']+':'+item['password']));
        return this._http.post(this._beconfig.Server + "login/api/" + resrc, {headers: this.headers})
            .timeoutWith(5000, Observable.throw(new Error('Request timed out.')))
            .map((response: Response) => { return response; })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Still my browser prompt a alert to enter user name and password.

Can you please help whats going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure username and password is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending your headers in the request body instead of the options part.

Here's the implementation or the post method if you are using the angular Http module:

```js
post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>;
```

So you need a RequestOptions object in the third argument where you put your headers like this:

```js
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
this._http.post(this._beconfig.Server + "login/api/" + resrc, {}, options)
```

And if you are using HttpClient on Angular 4.3+, the implementation of the post method is a bit different:

```js
post(url: string, body: any | null, options: {...}): Observable<any>
```

And to use it you should write your code like this:

```js
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
this._http.post(this._beconfig.Server + "login/api/" + resrc, {}, {headers: headers})
```

Comment: Thanks @e.m.b , sending null body {} was what I missed.